# Is there any ways to capture the values of ISO and shutter speed values of Camera using React Native for Android device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

New to React-native just wanted to know that if i take a picture from android device , how can i get the ISO and shutter speed values .Is there any way to capture these values.How can we access these values in react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, need to write own native module, or add additional native function to react-native-camera to work with this props